# Update value inside android manifest

Tags: android, sqlite, manifest

I can easily grab values from my database, declare them in my java file and use them in my xml design. My problem is trying to use these database variables in my manifest. I want the user's username to display in the `android:label`.

This is my current manifest but I'm having no luck:

```
<activity android:name="Main"
              android:label="@id/uname">
```

Any ideas on how I can display the users username from my database into my manifest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot update values in the manifest file like you're trying to do. Values in the manifest file are not updateble when the appliction runs.

If you want to display the user's name in the title, you can use this method from the activity:

```
setTitle(CharSequence title)
```

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation, I was going crazy trying to get the value inside the manifest haha